# How to show comment's post with file on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My realtionship is like this: post `Req.php` have many comments `CommentsRequest.php` and comments have many file `FileRequest.php`. How to get file's detail from specified comments of post?

The model:

```
//Req.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'profil_id', 'id');
}
public function commentsRequest()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentRequest');
}

//CommentRequest.php
public function request()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Req');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'profil_id', 'id');
}
public function filesRequest()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\FileRequest', 'comreq_id');
}

//FileRequest.php
public function commentsRequest()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CommentRequest', 'comreq_id', 'id_comreq');
}
```

Store comment in `CommentController.php`

```
public function store($id)
{
    $files = Input::file('filefield');
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $request = Req::find($id);
    $isi = Input::get('comment');
    $comment = CommentRequest::create(array('req_id' => $id, 'profil_id' => $user, 'comment' => $isi ));

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $names = "";
        $x = new FileRequest();

        if($validator->passes()){
        $destinationPath = 'uploads/request';
        $mime = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $names .= $filename;

        $x->filename = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$mime;
        $x->type = $mime;
        $x->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $comment->filesRequest()->save($x);
        }
    }

    return view('request.show', compact('request'));
}
```

I want to show comment with file on view with this code but error

```
  <ul>
        @foreach($request->commentsRequest as $comment)
              <h5>{{ $comment->komentar }} by {{ $comment->user->name }}</h5>
              @foreach($comments->filesRequest->all() as $file)
                    <h5>{{ $file->filename }}</h5>
              @endforeach

        @endforeach
  </ul>
```

How to solve this? I have stack with this problem. Sorry for bad english

Comment: What is not working for you? What is the outcome you're getting?

Comment: just comment not with the filename

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Could you paste sample HTML output that you're getting and the one you'd like to get instead?

Comment: `<ul><h5>Request by John</h5></ul>`. But if I write `dd($request->commentsRequest->filesRequest[0]->filename);` the error  is Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$filesRequest

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this **Undefined property** error because you're trying to fetch **$filesRequest** property from **$comments** variable, which is a collection of comments. You need to fetch it from individual **$comment**:

```
@foreach($comment->filesRequest->all() as $file)
  <h5>{{ $file->filename }}</h5>
@endforeach
```

You can also skip the call to **all()** because **$comment->filesRequest** returns the collection already, so the following should be enough:

```
@foreach($comment->filesRequest as $file)
  <h5>{{ $file->filename }}</h5>
@endforeach
```

Comment: it's still not working, just show comment only not with the file

Comment: yes Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$filesRequest

Comment: Did you replace $comments->filesRequest with $comment->filesRequest? You're still trying to access this variable on the collection instead of a single object\

Comment: of course, still not show the file's comment. I guess it's about specific comment which want to show , this code work `dd($request->commentsRequest[0]->comment) //comment is attribute`. But if `dd($request->commentsRequest[0]->filesRequest->all()->filename);` showing Trying to get property of non-object error.

Comment: all() returns an array, that's why you're getting the error. Try to dd($request->commentsRequest[0]->filesRequest) and see if there are items in this collection.

Comment: yes, but the array is empty. So how to show the requst with comment and comment's file attribute? With this relationship like : request hasmany comment and commnet hasmany file